# TLS/certificate issue on iOS 14 using certs that worked on iOS 13 [NSURLErrorDomain, Error Code: -1202]

Tags: ios, ssl, updates, ios14, nsurlerrordomain

I'm working on a React-Native app that displays a local website via WKWebView. I just updated to iOS 14 and now I'm getting cert issues again. I was not getting this error yesterday but after installing the update I am met with this awful error message:

`"Error loading page"`

[React-Native WebView Error Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFgwq.jpg)

In the Metro console, I get the WARN message:

`Encountered an error loading page {"canGoBack": false, "canGoForward": false, "code": -1202, "description": "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “10.0.1.10” which could put your confidential information at risk.", "didFailProvisionalNavigation": true, "domain": "NSURLErrorDomain", "loading": false, "target": 7, "title": "", "url": ""}`

Comment: Have you found any solution for this. I am facing same error while trying to upload any file to my server

Comment: @Priyanka Yes I had to go thru the whole process of creating a CA, then generating the certs without using a self signed cert.

Comment: Can you please explain me whole process?

Comment: @Priyanka You can read the full process here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2326/_index.html